# Linear programming model for a retail online order

Tags: linear-programming

I'm reading up on Linear Programming and wanted to build a model for a scenario where there a set of N nodes should be found to be source for an order that has S set of items

\begin{align}
N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_n &\Rightarrow \text{ Nodes that hold items} \\
S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_m &\Rightarrow \text{ Items requested in an order} \\
n &= \text{ Total number of nodes} \\
    m &= \text{ Total number of items in the order} \\
    R(S_j) &= \text{ Requested quantity of item } S_j \\ 
    T(N_i) &= \text{ Shipping cost to ship the order from $N_i$ (or part of the order} \\
& \quad\,\,\text{ if only some of the items are decided to be shipped from $N_i$)} \\
    A(Ni, Sj) &= \text{ Quantities of $S_j$ available at node $N_i$}
\end{align}

These values are available. The following values will be produced as solution:
\begin{align}
  Q(N_i, S_j) &= \text{ Quantity of item $S_j$ that will be shipped from node $N_i$} \\
  Y(N_i) &= \text{ Binary variable to denote if Node $N_i$ was selected as one of the} \\
&\quad\,\,\text{ source nodes. Allowed value $= 0$ (if not selected) or $1$ (if selected)} \\
    1 \leq i &\leq n \\
    1 \leq j &\leq m
\end{align}
With these variables, I build the following objective function-

$$f = \sum_i [T(N_i)\cdot Y(N_i)] \text{ Total shipping cost from all the selected nodes}$$
such that

\begin{align}
\textstyle\sum_i [Q(N_i,S_j)] &= R(S_j) \text{ Quantities of item $S_j$ shipped from all the nodes} \\
&\quad\text{ should be equal to the requested quantity} \\
Q(N_i,S_j) &\leq A(N_i,S_j) \text{ Quantities of $S_j$ shipping from node $N_i$ should} \\
&\quad\text{ be less than or equal to available quantity of $S_j$ at node $N_i$}
\end{align}
Does this model look right? Am I missing something in building the model?

Also, how good of an option is linear programming for this type of scenarios in real world?

Comment: How do you plan to constrain the $Y$ variables?

Comment: 0 <= Y(N_i) <= 1

(Thanks for editing)

Comment: You're welcome.  What prevents the LP solver from setting all $Y$ variables to $0$?  The connection between the $Q$ variables and the $Y$ variables is missing.

Comment: maybe add a constraint something like - "Y(N_i) = 1 if (Sum_over_j Q(N_i,S_j) > 0) else 0 ". Do you mean something like this?

Comment: In principle, yes, but that would not be a linear constraint and you wouldn't be able to use an LP solver.  Instead, you can change the upper bound on $Q(N_i,S_j)$ to $A(N_i,S_j) \cdot Y(N_i)$.